# Check if an object is a Type in Google Closure, and convert it?

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler, typechecking

How can I check (at runtime) if an unknown object is a certain type? And then formally convert it to that type and do something with it?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
const /** {Object} */ someObject = {name: 'Apple', color: 'Red'};
if (someObject is Fruit) {
  // Convert to {Fruit} and do something with it.
  return /** {Fruit} */ (someObject);
}
```

where `Fruit` is a class with the attributes name and color.

To be more specific, I can't just create a `Fruit` object with a constructor as I'm getting the object from `JSON.parse`.

So far I've tried:

```
if (someObject instanceof Fruit)
```

this resolved to false. And I've tried:

```
const aFruit = /** @type {Fruit} */ someObj;
```

But this doesn't actually seem to do anything.. ie, when I pass in `someObj` that doesn't have properties name or color it is still treated as a `Fruit`.

Perhaps I need a more complex/custom solution? ie, is this built into Closure or should I just check the attributes on my own?

Comment: Closure types only exist at compile time.

Comment: With some additional explanation of how type converting `/** @type {Fruit} */` works/why it doesn't work here, I'd accept "you can't; do this on your own" as an answer.

Comment: The `instanceof` test works only when the object is created with `new` (or perhaps when the JavaScript `property` values are manually arranged).  Do you have ways to test what type of object it is from the properties?  if so you can use type-casting as you show in your first example.

Comment: Could you do something like `const aFruit = goog.object.extend(new Fruit, someObject)` ? Alternatively, `Object.assign(new Fruit, someObject)` may work; its a newer method, so you can tell the compiler to include polyfill with `--rewrite_polyfills` flag if you want your code to work on older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instanceof` is what you are looking for. That's how you check if any given value was created from a specific constructor function (or better ES2015 class).

```
const /** {Object} */ someObject = new Fruit('Apple', 'red'); 
if (someObject instanceof Fruit) {
  // Convert to {Fruit} and do something with it.
  return /** {Fruit} */ (someObject);
}
```

However in your original example, what makes an object a Fruit? You are using anonymous objects. Is any object that has a `name` and `color` property a fruit? This is a bit unclear and very implementation specific. You need to be able to answer yourself "What makes an object a fruit?"

If you want to check if an object implements a Fruit interface (has the correct properties), you simply check for those properties:

```
/**
 * @param {!Object} obj
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function isFruit(obj) {
  return obj.color && obj.name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Closure's typesystem only exists at compile time.

Just like in C, casts simply tell the type system "I guarantee that this value actually is of this type, even though you can't prove it".
If that isn't true, you get undefined behavior (especially with advanced optimizations).

Comment: This isn't strictly true. Most types are based off of constructors or interfaces. Either can be checked at runtime.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: Interfaces can't be.

Comment: Sure they can - an interface is just a set of properties. If an object has properties that match the specific types, that can be checked at runtime.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: But you can't check the types of the interface members.  Also, depending on how you declare your interface and what optimization settings you use, the interface members may not be available at all at runtime.

Comment: You can also check the types of interface members. `typeof myobj.prop === 'string' `. The presence of such a check ensures that the property will not be removed as dead code.